Portable AC unit takes a long time before it finally starts blowing air
I have a portable AC unit in my room which has the issue of not starting or taking very long to start blowing air, let alone cold air. Once it finally starts blowing air however, it works fine and you don't notice anything off with the AC. It's just that it doesn't start blowing (cold) air as soon as you turn it on, like it should.
After a bit of searching online I'm thinking it might be the capacitor that isn't able to provide the initial power jolt to start the unit. If I turn on the AC and I'm lucky, after 5-10 minutes it finally suddenly starts blowing air. Once it's blowing, it will continue blowing just fine without issues until I turn it off again.
Is this a possible bad capicator that I could replace? Any other suggestions as to what component might be causing this issue?

good research on your part. I would agree with you on bad capacitor

Make and model? Capacitor size and type varies.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact It’s a MOA A010B. Unfortunately not much technical stuff to find about it

Has it always worked this way, or slowly gotten worse? Does it make any noise when it is not starting? It could also be hot-start protection which is either very cheaply made and always assumes a hot start, or which is malfunctioning.

@KMJ It’s slowly gotten worse over time. In the beginning it always started blowing air roughly 3-5 seconds after turning it on. It doesn’t make any noise, but occasionally you hear a faint ticking.
This week I actually replaced the relay in the circuit and it worked perfectly for a day, but now it has the exact same issue again…
